# Strange JQuery for loop anomaly when using 'keyup'

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, click

On my webpage I have 32 checkboxes all with IDs "U1C1", "U1C2" etc...

I am using a piece of JQuery to show coresponding rows of a table with the ID "U1C1_table", "U1C2_table" etc...

```
for (var x = 1; x<33;x++) {
$('#U1C' + x).on("keyup change",function() {

if(this.checked) {
   $('#U' + x + '_TABLE').show('');
}
else {
   $('#U1_TABLE').hide('slow');
}

});
}
```

I have used a for loop to speed this up.

This code does not work, however if I change the **second** x to a 1 then it will work for the first row. This is strange because if it wouldn't evaluate to the same code, why does the first x  found in

```
$('#U1C' + x).on("keyup change",function() {
```

work fine?

EDIT: MY HTML

```
 C1 <input type="checkbox" id="U1C1" value ="U1C1">
 C2 <input type="checkbox" id="U1C2" value ="U1C2">
 C3 <input type="checkbox" id="U1C3" value ="U1C3">
 C4 <input type="checkbox" id="U1C4" value ="U1C4">
<tr id="U1_TABLE"><td>UNIT ONE</td><td>dropdown</td><td>textbox</td></tr>
<tr id="U1C1_TABLE"><td>UNIT ONE</td><td>dropdown</td><td>textbox</td></tr>
<tr id="U1C2_TABLE"><td>UNIT ONE</td><td>dropdown</td><td>textbox</td></tr>
```

Comment: Need some HTML markup to see how you're structuring the tables and checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry missed some off, fixed.

Comment: classic problem of not using a closure ... `x` is not the same value when the code runs inside the event handler. It will always be the maximum value of the loop

Comment: Your id attributes on the `<tr>` tags are inconsistent. Use consistent tags. You're only binding to U1, U2, U3 not U1C1, U1C2, U1C3. Also check the `} else {` since it's only hiding the first table.

Comment: Thank you guys now I have fixed both errors now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself some code, and make use of a common class, along with a custom data attribute:

```
C1 <input type="checkbox" class="table-cb" data-number="1" id="U1C1" value ="U1C1">
C2 <input type="checkbox" class="table-cb" data-number="2" id="U1C2" value ="U1C2">
C3 <input type="checkbox" class="table-cb" data-number="3" id="U1C3" value ="U1C3">
C4 <input type="checkbox" class="table-cb" data-number="4" id="U1C4" value ="U1C4">
```

And the jQuery

```
$(".table-cb").change(function() {
    var num = $(this).data("number");
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#U' + num + '_TABLE').show('');
    } else {
        $('#U' + num + '_TABLE').hide('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about data-number

Comment: @EdByrne -- It's not just data-number, data-* can be any custom attribute. The data- prefix just ensures it'll pass validation